# Javascript JQuery scollTop reset when scolling back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

hi i have the following

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() > 200){
       $('.ccbrtlogo').css({'height': '25'});
       $('.ccbrtlogo').css({'margin-top': '0'}); 
     }else{
         $('.ccbrtlogo').css({'height': '50'}); 
         $('.ccbrtlogo').css({'margin-top': '16'});
     } 
});
```

it does work when i scoll down it sets the logo to a small 25px height and changes the margin-top to 0 but when i scoll back up it only changes the logo back to 50 but does not apply the 16px margin-top

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add also the **measurement unit**. In case of `0`, you can put nothing after it because everything: `0px`, `0in` are `0`. But with another number you need to use `16px` instead of `16`

```
$('.ccbrtlogo').css({'margin-top': '16px'});
```

**Example**

```js
$('#first').css({'margin-top': '100'});
$('#second').css({'margin-top': '100px'});
```

```css
div{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">
  First
</div>

<div id="second">
  Second
</div>
```

Comment: This explains a lot. Great help.